# how do I select the "root" div in react app

Tags: reactjs, sass

I have a div with id='root', I have sccs file where I can select body and change its stile (so, scss sheet is working), the first child in the body is that div (since it's a react app). No matter what I use, I can't select it. I used:

```
#root {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body:first-child{
}
```

nothing works

Comment: [id="root"] worked, I have no idea why i can't use #root

Answer (score 1):

[first-child](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.php) is used to select an element that is **the first child of its parent.** Therefore, `body:first-child` is incorrect. It selects the 1st `body` tag in its parent which is `html`.

If you want to select the 1st `div` in `body`, use `body div:first-child`